# Django Group By Aggregation works until additional fields added

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I'd like to group the following track variations at the given circuit so on an index page I only have a single entry for each circuit.  On a subsequent circuit detail page I will show the various configurations.

[image]

If I keep the query simple as below it works.

```
    track_listing = (Tracks.objects
                 .values('sku', 'track_name')
                 .annotate(variations=Count('sku'))
                 .order_by()
                 )
```

However adding other fields such as track_id or location breaks or changes the grouping.

```
        track_listing = (Tracks.objects
                 .values('sku', 'track_name', 'track_id')
                 .annotate(variations=Count('sku'))
                 .order_by()
                 )
```

Is there a way to keep the group while including other fields.  The location is not unique to each row and having one example of track_id allows me to retrieve a track image.

Comment: If you only want "having one example of track_id allows me to retrieve a track image", you can simply annotate a min or max: .annotate(one_track_id=Min('track_id')) after your annotate

Comment: @royshoo Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately this does not work and gets me back to retrieving multiples.

Comment: Hi, regarding your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75969964/django-order-by-ascending-with-none-last-with-second-level-order-for-nones I do not manage to reproduce it. It would be nice to include the database backend, etc. such that, if this is a bug, we can report and fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to resolve this issue is to group the results by the `sku` and `track_name` fields, and use a separate query to retrieve the `track_id` and other details for each track variation, like the following:

```py
# First query to retrieve the track variations
track_variations = (Tracks.objects
                    .values('sku', 'track_name')
                    .annotate(variations=Count('sku'))
                    .order_by())

# Loop through the track variations and retrieve additional details for each variation
for track in track_variations:
    # Second query to retrieve details for each track variation
    track_details = Tracks.objects.filter(sku=track['sku'], track_name=track['track_name']).values('track_id', 'location', 'other_fields')
    track['variations'] = list(track_details)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use subquery for that.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

subquery = Tracks.objects.filter(
    sku=OuterRef('sku'),
    track_name=OuterRef('track_name')
).values('track_id')[:1]

track_listing = (Tracks.objects
    .annotate(track_id=Subquery(subquery))
    .values('sku', 'track_name', 'track_id')
    .annotate(variations=Count('sku'))
    .order_by()
    .distinct('sku', 'track_name')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Sadly, doesn't seem to work.    If I add flat=True as per your example I get "'flat' is not valid when values_list is called with more than one field" and without it there is an error and None is returned.

Comment: @ByteInsight, I already updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around.   I've been able to get a working solution using @Sunderam's suggestion which your solution parallels.