# Django - Order by Ascending with None Last with second level order for Nones

Tags: django, django-queryset

As per the title I'd like to order the Fastest Lap values in ascending times with any Nones at the end sorted by Laps Complete descending.

The model fields are

```
...
laps_complete = models.IntegerField(null=True)
best_lap_time = models.IntegerField(null=True)
...
```

My first attempt was

```
simsession['results'] = LeagueSessionResults.objects.all()
    .filter(session_id=subsession_id,
            simsession_number=simsession['simsession_number']
    )
    .order_by(F('best_lap_time').desc(nulls_last=True), "-laps_complete")
```

which returns the correct order except that Fastest Lap times are descending:

[image: Fastest Lap Descending with correct laps complete on None]

So on the basis of [Model Meta options - Ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) we attempt to change the Fastest Lap order by swapping desc/asc to

```
.order_by(F('best_lap_time').asc(nulls_last=True), "-laps_complete")
```

and this returns where the None values are now at the top:

[image: Fastest Lap Ascending but completed laps given first]

The solution is to check that you actually have NONE values where you believe to have NONE values and then the following filter will work perfectly.

```
.order_by(
    F('best_lap_time').asc(nulls_last=True),
    F('laps_complete').desc(nulls_last=True)
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the model and perhaps some part of the `dumpdata`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I have undeleted the question and inserted the solution I found.    The underlying problem was one of my own doing.    I didn't have the head space at the time to document it but as you have asked on another question of mine I felt inclined to produce something.   The model is just numbers representing the results of a race - nothing clever.